# How to insert a money amount in Android App?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm building an Android app and I want the users to be able to insert an amount of money. For this I want two boxes, one for the whole number of Euro's, and one for the decimals. For this I can of course us two textViews and convert the contents to a BigDecimal (the type we use for money denominations). There are two downside to this though;

1. I want the soft keyboard that pops up to only display numbers, and not letters, and of course, the box should only accept numbers as well.
2. When a person clicks the dot, I want it to automatically switch to the decimal box.

When defining the xml I can't find any specific "numberView" or something similar. Seeing that this occurs in more than just our app, I suppose there is a better way of doing this. I searched around, but I can't really find what I'm looking for (although I might search for the wrong words).

So my question; does anybody know how I should handle inserting money amounts in an Android app?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question: `ardroid:inputType="numberDecimal"`

For your second question: Add a click listener to the dot view (textbox, or whatever it is) to focus on the second EditText.

Edit: If the user has a non standard keyboard, it may not accept the numberDecimal input type. It may also be a good idea to set set `android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"`

Answer (score 1):

Steps :

1)Use android:inputType="numberDecimal"

2) Then implement TextWatcher in your java class.

3) Inside onCreate() method set listener

EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
e1.addTextChangedListener(this);

4)

```
@Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        if (arg0.toString().contains(".")) {
            // e2.requestFocus(); // Set focus to second editText
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! For the line "e1.addTextChangedListener(this);" however, I get a message saying "The method addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments 
 (MainActivity)". I tried changing "this" to onTextChanged, but that simply says that onTextChanged cannot be resolved or is not a field, even though I included it in the mainActivity class. Any tips?

Comment: addTextChangedListener is for editText, not for TextView. Since you want to take input from user, i think you need EditText here.